# How to specify an instance with a subclass without typing hint errors?

Tags: python, mypy

I'm using instance `__class__` attribute to specify an instance created from the super class. But MyPy rejects it with `Incompatible return value type`.

Is there a most pythonic option to do that without ignoring it?

Here is my example code:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, a: int = None):
        self.a = a or 1


class B(A):
    def b(self) -> int:
        return 5 + self.a

    @classmethod
    def specify(cls, a_instance: A) -> 'B':
        a_instance.__class__ = cls
        return a_instance  # type: ignore


if __name__ == "__main__":
    s = A(6)
    s = B.specify(s)
    print(s.b())
```

and the error if you don't ignore typing:

```
 % mypy scratch_7.py
scratch_7.py:13: error: Incompatible return value type (got "A", expected "B")
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

Comment: add full error Trackback here

Comment: @ARMAN there is not any Traceback on this error. It's just a typing error message. It runs ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mypy [supports dynamically type casting](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/casts.html) with the use of `typing.cast`.

```
from typing import cast

class B(A):
    def b(self) -> int:
        return 5 + self.a

    @classmethod
    def specify(cls, a_instance: A) -> 'B':
        a_instance.__class__ = cls
        a_instance = cast('B', a_instance)
        return a_instance

# Success: no issues found in 1 source file
```

`typing.cast` doesn't change the value, it only signals the type checker (mypy) that the type has changed.